# How can I select integers from a list in Prolog?

Tags: list, prolog

I'm trying to create a predicate in Prolog `select_integers(X, L)` that holds true if `L` is a list containing every integer in `X` (`X` contains multiple types of values).

Here's what I have so far:

```
select_integers([], []).
select_integers([X|XS], L) :-
    integer(X),
    member(X, L),
    select_integers(XS, L).
```

What am I missing here? How can I improve this to get the result I want? (It currently returns `false` for whatever I do)

Comment: `?- include(integer, YourList, Integers).`

Comment: @CapelliC: Incorrectly succeeds for `include(integer,[I], []), I = 1.`

Comment: @false: I know. But, I think that someone who *start* coding in *Prolog* should *not* care about. Sure, it's *my* opinion...

Comment: @CapelliC: Someone who starts coding needs to learn how errors in a program can be localized.

Comment: @false: and where should be located the error in `include(integer,[I],[]), I=1` ? Library implementation, I suppose... Doesn't seem a good introduction to Prolog for a newbie. Sure, it's *my* opinion...

Comment: @CapelliC: Just look at my answer below: The generalization I used only works if the entire program is pure and monotonic. So when you use such non-monotonic constructs as `include/3` you cannot use generalizations at all (or which extremely high effort that a beginner cannot master).

Comment: @CapelliC: Also you cannot use the **most general query** to see all solutions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111390/discussion-between-capellic-and-false).

Comment: @CapelliC: Chat only in the evening. Too much work now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need another case.

case1 for the empty list.

case 2 for when the item is an integer add it to the second list

case 3 for when the item is not an integer dont add it to the second list.

```
select_integers([],[]).
select_integers([X|XS],[X|L]) :-
 integer(X),
 select_integers(XS,L).
select_integers([X|XS],L) :-
 \+integer(X),
 select_integers(XS,L).
```

You can and might want to change it so that L does not have duplicates if x has duplicates. You could do this with another case, or a separate predicate.

You could also make it more relational maybe by looking at the reif stuff e.g in swi http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/swi/reif.pl  for example a start could be:

```
int_t(X,T):-
 integer(X),
 T = true.
int_t(X,T):-
 \+integer(X),
 T = false.

 ?- tinclude(int_t,[a,b,1,2,3,4,5],X).
 X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] .
```

This is not fully relational though, as :

```
?- tinclude(int_t,[A,B],[A,B]).
false.
```

Both of these are not complete answers, but might help you along.

Comment: Note that `int_t(X,true), X = 1` incorrectly fails.

Comment: And so does `select_integers([X],[X]), X = 1`. This should be either an instantiation error or success.

Comment: Here a quick-and-dirty implementation: `int_t(X,T) :- ( integer(X) -> T=true ; nonvar(X) -> T=false ; freeze(X,int_t(X,T)) ).`

Comment: @repeat: From the outside, I cannot detect any dirt - just the inner part is a bit, erm, efficient.

Comment: Thanks so much! Your answer is extremely helpful! Just one question though, what does the \+ operator do?

Comment: \+ is not.
so \+integer(X) is true when X is not an integer. 
And thanks, but do study false's answer it is better!  It deals with more types of queries correctly.

Comment: Be aware that `integer(X)` is not monotonic: it tests for the right type *and* the right instantiation.

Answer (score 4):

If I look into your program, I see `integer(X)` which is better replaced by `when(nonvar(X), integer(X))` since it has otherwise no declarative meaning. Just believe me.

But now, once you have a pure program, we can locate the errors thanks to the declarative properties of Prolog.

The best is to ask Prolog directly, what it thinks:

```
?- select_integers(Xs, Ys).
   Xs = Ys, Ys = []  % expected success
;  loops.
```

Not much. The loop does not help us. It simply says that Prolog's engine got into an infinite loop no matter why. But we can specialize the query. Like so:

```
?- Xs = [_], Ys = [_], select_integers(Xs, Ys).
   false. % unexpected failure
```

Maybe you would have preferred `Xs = [1], Ys = [1]` instead. I just tried the possible maximum.

Remark that I had to restrict both `Xs` and `Ys` to a list with a single element.  Otherwise the query loops.

The situation is now much better, for an unexpected failure means that we can diagnose the program. In particular, we can generalize the program by removing some parts. I found this generalization of your program:

```
:- initialization( ( Xs = [_], Ys = [_], select_integers(Xs, Ys) ) ).
:- op(950, fy, *).
*_.

select_integers(_/*[]*/,[]).
select_integers([X|XS],L) :-
   * when(nonvar(X), integer(X) ),
   * member(X,L),
   select_integers(XS,L).
```

<sub>(To obtain that fragment, I saved everything into a file, added `*` to some goals and said `make` repeatedly (which is built-in in SWI and there is [this module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34560693/772868) for SICStus), always looking out for an error message that the goal failed. So I tried to take away from your program as much as possible)</sub>

Everything that remained is responsible for the failure. Everything else is not needed to produce the failure. It might be right or wrong, we know not. Actually the culprit is the `L`! If you look at the rule reading it right-to-left, it reads:

> Provided `select_integers(XS,L)` is true, then it follows (the `:-` is meant to symbolize an arrow) that `select_integers([X|XS], L)` is true.

In other words, the second argument will always remain of the same length. And there is only `[]`! So the second argument can only be the empty list.

```
select_integers([],[]).
select_integers([X|XS],[X|L]) :-
   when(nonvar(X), integer(X) ),
   select_integers(XS,L).

?- Xs = [_], select_integers(Xs, Ys).
   Xs = Ys, Ys = [_A],
   when(nonvar(_A), integer(_A)).
   % missing further answer
```

So this program is now true for lists being all integers. But it still fails for lists not being integers. Here is a quick fix for this:

```
select_integers([],[]).
select_integers([X|XS],[X|L]) :-
   when(nonvar(X), integer(X) ),
   select_integers(XS,L).
select_integers([X|XS],L) :-
   when(nonvar(X), \+integer(X) ),
   select_integers(XS,L).

?- Xs = [_], select_integers(Xs, Ys).
   Xs = Ys, Ys = [_A],
   when(nonvar(_A), integer(_A))
;  Xs = [_A], Ys = [],
   when(nonvar(_A), \+integer(_A)).
```

There are more concise ways to express this. As with:

```
integer_t(X, T) :-
   when(nonvar(X), ( integer(X) -> T = true ; T = false ) ).

select_integers(Xs, Is) :-
   tfilter(integer_t, Xs, Is).
```

In a system that does not support `when/2` (nor `freeze/2`) you can still be on the safe side with:

```
integer_t(X, T) :-
   functor(X,_,_),
   ( integer(X) -> T = true ; T = false ).
```

Using [`tfilter/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22053194/772868).