# How to make Prolog on terminal notice the new changes added to a Prolog source file?

Tags: terminal, text-editor, swi-prolog

I open a SWI-Prolog through terminal with `Swipl -s prolog_file` . However, each time I add new facts to the Prolog source file and save, I have to restart SWI-Prolog on terminal to make it notice the changes.

I thought using `CTRL + s` on the Prolog source file is enough to let SWI-Prolog notice the changes but it doesn't.

On windows there is a Prolog editor with compile button, when you compile the file, SWI-Prolog will notice the changes, but I'm using Kali Linux, so I'm writing on text editor.

How can I make SWI-Prolog notice the changes ?

Comment: When you get the `?-` prompt, type `make.`

Comment: See also "[Reloading files, active code and threads](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=loadrunningcode)". Having lived for 15 years with pathetic Java Classloader problems, I find this amazing. It's also very non-logical and one immediately wonders whether predicates are re-versioned in transactions.

Comment: When someone post an answer that is acceptable it is polite to accept the answer by clicking on the check mark next to the up down triangles for the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you get the `?-` prompt, type `make.`

This is a [built-in in SWI](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=make/0), it can be [simulated in SICStus](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34558948/772868).

For complex projects including a lot of preprocessing and modules this feature may not work.

Comment: ECliPSe and YAP also provide a `make/0` predicate. Logtalk provides a portable `make` tool that can be used with most Prolog systems.