# Is there a way to automatically "consult" files on prolog?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I am kind of annoyed by having to manually re-consult my prolog every time I made changes in its source file.

Can I make it run automatically somehow? I have searched for some extensions on vscode IDE, but could not come to a solution. Any ideas or scripts?

Comment: In SWI Prolog, query `?- help(editreload).` particularly the third bit "3.3.2 Editing and incremental compilation".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just say `make` in SWI. Similar functionality is available for [SICStus](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34558948/772868).

Comment: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=make/0 is a different operation to https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=consult/1

Comment: @brebs it might be that OP meant the question in the way this answer approaches it

Comment: @brebs: when would there be a notable difference to OP? `consult/1` always consults, even if nothing changed. Is this the difference you are referring to?

Comment: `make` reloads (and shows code warnings for, if applicable) *all* loaded files (including e.g. `~/.config/swi-prolog/init.pl` for swi-prolog), whereas the user might only intend to reload a single file, if performing finely-grained debugging.

Comment: So `ensure_loaded/1` as defined in SICStus would be the ideal for you. That is, only reload if things changed in the meantime.

Answer (score -1):

As a little helper to minimize the inconvenience, could add a tiny predicate to the start of your script file, as a shortcut to call [consult](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=consult/1), e.g.:

```
c :-
    % Reload 'clumped2.pl' with just: c.
    consult('clumped2').
```

Then, to reload:

```
c.
```